# Instant Messaging Between Android phone and PC

Tags: android, instant-messaging

I use universal IM clients for both my PC and my Android phone. I'm running Digsby on my PC and the Trillian client on my Android.

I'm not specifically attached to either piece of software, they're just what's worked for me so far. I do however have an annoyance in that I will receive messages on both my phone and my PC at once. What I really want to be able to do is only have the messages on my PC when I am on my PC, then only have messages on my phone when I'm wandering about.

Has anyone tried to solve a similar problem?

Comment: why don't you just log off of the im client on your phone when you don't need it? If you want to get crazy/lazy with it, you can probaly setup tasker to kill the app when your gps hits your home or something.

Comment: @acme64 -- of course always a viable option, I would just rather avoid having to turn it off every time considering how often this would happen (every time I stand up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is actually just use [Trillian](http://trillian.im) on both my phone and desktop.

Trillian saves recent chat on every device, but only alerts you on your phone if you're idle at your desktop. So I can literally get up mid-conversation and talk on my phone without having to remember what I was talking about. Doesn't always work perfectly, but better than anything else I've found.

Only caveat is Trillian is ad-supported in the free version. You're also out of luck if you aren't a supported platform.